# I want To Seek Forgiveness For This Sin

Tags: halal-haram

Is it Haram if an Older man had did pleasure on you when you were younger but you didn’t know if what he was doing to you was Haram ? And how can you been forgiven for that sin?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn’t know that then it doesn’t count.